# Connecting Mysql with Visual Studio 2015 C#

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2015

So...
I've been doing a project using Mysql and visual studio in C# and everything is working fine, but when I tried to create a new project and connect Mysql the following error appears.

```
OdbcConnection MyConn = new OdbcConnection(myConnectionString);
MyConn.Open();
```

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException'
>   occurred in System.Data.dll

Comment: That could be because of many reason. Moreover, why not use `MySQLConnection` instead?

Comment: Post the exception message along with entire stack trace

Comment: Hi Rahul, I read a book that taught me that this way... so I'm not used to code with MySQLConnection. Do you have any guess of what the problem could be? I don't know why my current project isn't opening the ODBC connector... considering that another project works perfectly.

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: ERROR [IM014] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] O DSN especificado contém uma incompatibilidade de arquiteturas entre o Driver e o Aplicativo (It says that the DSN has an architecture incompatibility between the Driver and the application.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by installing 32 bit ODBC